# Getting Photoshop CC to always save to the last used location?

Tags: windows-7, windows, adobe-photoshop

When I'm working with a PSD for example in Photoshop CC and I save assets (Export) it remembers the last location fine.

But sometimes I might want to save something directly via the menu using the "File -> Export -> Save for web (Legacy)" then it doesn't use the last location where I saved something, it always defaults to the Desktop and then I have to go through the whole process of finding the directory.

Is there any way I can get it to always default to using the last location used?

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: That's an OS feature… but you didn't say what OS you're on

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh sorry, I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop is programmed to do what you are seeing, by an unwise use of the Windows API
by the Photoshop developer who coded that function.

You can't solve the problem, only improve it perhaps by installing a
Save dialog enhancement product.

Some such products may be found on
[this page](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=Save+dialog).